# Javascript object properties with same values experience the same changes when they shouldn't (splice)

Tags: javascript, splice

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I have a complete misunderstanding of Javascript, but this is what happens:

I take an object with two arrays inside it, one representing the current queue of IDs and another representing the total queue of IDs (hypothetical situation)

```
var mainObject = {
    object1:[],
    object2:[]
};
```

In a function, we set the two property arrays to the same variable which holds the array needed before we can start processing the queue.

```
var randomVar = [1,2,3,4];
mainObject.object1 = randomVar;
mainObject.object2 = randomVar;
```

Now we want to make use of the splice method to remove the first index from object1 while keeping it on object two.

```
mainObject.object1.splice(0,1);
```

The result of the object is now as follows:

```
mainObject = {
    object1:[2,3,4],
    object2:[2,3,4]
};
```

meaning that both of the properties were spliced when we only asked Javascript to run it once.

See JS Fiddle for live example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ypow6y8g/

Is there something I'm missing or is this just another night spent with loose JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have one array, and two variables whose value is a reference to that array. When you modify the value of one of those variables, you modify the other one as it's the same.

If you want your arrays to be independent, clone one:

```
var randomVar = [1,2,3,4];
mainObject.object1 = randomVar;
mainObject.object2 = randomVar.slice(); // slice returns a new array
```